# In rails-ember app, how do I render a bg-image in css and make it fit the browser?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript, zurb-foundation

I have an ember app that is built on top of a rails backend with Foundation as the responsive framework.

On the homepage, index.hbs, I would like to display a background-image that is sized the width/height of the browser. To do this, in my index.hbs file I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns home-bg">
    <h1>EW</h1>
</div>
```

I have .row set to a width of 100% in my css file. Then to size the .home-bg div to the size of the browser I have the following in index_view.coffee

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend(didInsertElement: ->
  $(window).resize ->
    $(".home-bg").height $(window).height()
)
```

And lastly, in my css file:

```
.home-bg {
  background: image-url("home_bg.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But when I load the page the height of the div isn't being calculated and the background image isn't even being loaded, it appears to be a broken link. I have the image in /assets/images.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I now have the background image loading. Now there's a weird issue of the home-bg div only being the height of the <h1> when I load the page, but as soon as I grab the corner of the browser to resize the div resizes according to the browser and bg image fills it out as hoped.

Any ideas why it isn't initially loading full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because when you grap the corner the `resize` event is dispacht for the first time and thus the div get's it's size set.

Try this dirty hack to see if it's working even at the beginning without resizing the window first:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend(didInsertElement: ->
  $(".home-bg").height $(window).height()
  $(window).resize ->
    $(".home-bg").height $(window).height()
)
```

Comment: That did it. I feel like resize() should account for the initial page load?

Comment: @reknirt, well not really because when the page initially loads the window is not resized, but you could also trigger it explicitly like `$.trigger('resize')`